# xcode How to show $ value in a Label and a Text Box. Example 125000 as 125,000.00

Tags: xcode, label

I need to show $value on a Label.
currently it appears as 125000 but i need it to be 125,000.00

thanks in advance to all supporters.

Comment: might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479882/nstextfield-with-automatic-nsnumberformatter-in-interface-builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of your problem is [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Some code to get you started:

```
    NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSLog(@"%@", [currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInt:10395209]]);
[currencyFormatter release];
```

Answer (score 0):

Drag the Number Formatter (found in the object library) object onto the field/label.  Change the behavior (be sure your in the attributes inspector for the number formatter) to 'OS X 10.4+ Custom' (that's what it was in Xcode 4.5.2).

In the 'Integer Digits' field, change the minimum to 1 and leave the maximum whatever you need.  For the 'Fraction Digits' fields set the minimum and maximum to 2.

Near the top of the field, stick a dollar sign in front of the 'Format (+)' and '(-)' fields.

Check the group separator box then change the primary and secondary grouping fields to 3.

Comment: HI,thanks for your contribute. however, im looking for solution for iOS 6. and i just started with Xcode and little bit confuse with your solution. just wonder, is their any solution to apply directly from storyboard. Thanks